# Why actionPerform() run in Event Dispatch Thread but componentAdded() is not?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, event-dispatch-thread

I have Ex1 below:

```
main(String args[]) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Title");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JButton button = new JButton("Press Here");
    ContainerListener container = new ContainerAdapter() {
      public void componentAdded(final ContainerEvent e) {
          System.out.println("On the event thread? : " +
                  EventQueue.isDispatchThread());
      }
    };
    frame.getContentPane().addContainerListener(container);
    frame.add(button, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setSize(200, 200);
    System.out.println("I'm about to be realized: " +
      EventQueue.isDispatchThread());
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
```

My result is: On the event thread? : FALSE | I'm about to be realized: false

Other Ex2:

```
public class GridBagLayoutTester
    extends JPanel implements ActionListener{   
public GridBagLayoutTester() {
    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

    JButton button = new JButton("Testing");
    // do something...
    button.addActionListener(this);
    add(button, gbc);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    System.out.println("On the event thread? : " +
                  EventQueue.isDispatchThread());
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("GridBagLayoutDemo");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);    
    Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    contentPane.add(new GridBagLayoutTester(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setSize(800, 600);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    System.out.println("I'm about to be realized: " +
      EventQueue.isDispatchThread());
}
```

}

result is: I'm about to be realized: false | On the event thread? : TRUE

My question is why Ex1- componentAdded() run in Intial Thread, but Ex2- actionPerformed() run in EDT ?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Please read the article on concurrency/EDT, referenced in the swing tag wiki (those basic infos are there .. for the reason of being read :-)

Comment: Thanks for you advises, AndrewThompson and kelopatra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your very first line in the main method creates a new object of type JFrame. This creation starts a new thread (in reality it starts more than one thread) - a new thread that waits for event queue items. This can be a mouse click for example.
To answer your question: The main thread - which is really called "main" - is invoking your 10 lines of code of the main method. This should be finished in some milliseconds. After that the main thread is gone, not existend anymore.
But as I said before, the AWT/Swing library has internally created one (yes, more) thread that is basically an ininite loop checking for user input. And the actionPerformed method is invoked from this thread.

My suggestion for you:

- Create a breakpoint in your first line of the main method.
- Debug your program.
- When the debugger stops at line one (before JFrame is created) go to your command line and start jconsole
- go to tab threads
- notice thread "main"
- execute single line (new JFrame)
- notice coexistence of thread "main" and thread(s) "AWT-*"
- press play on debugger and "main" will be gone but AWTs will persist

Comment: Thanks for your quickly answer. I debug and you right. But, Could you explain me more why in EX1, JFrame is created and AWT Thread is run, too, but componentAdded() does n't invoked from AWT ?

Comment: I suggest to use the debugger again. Set a breakpoint on your System.out in the componentAdded method. You will see that the call to frame.add is calling (through some other methods from swing) the componentAdded. Thus it is the main thread who is calling.

Comment: Means because Main thread is still exist so it will invoked compnentAdded. In Ex2, main thread is quit and delegate the work to EDT, and EDT will invoke actionPerformed(). is that right ?

Comment: It's not only a matter of "still existing". It' caused by the call hierarchy. Have a look at the stack trace. Try adding throw new Exception and catch it with printStackTrace. The main method calls Container.add which calls a lot of internal stuff and another method called processContainerEvents calls your componentAdded implementation.

Answer (score 3):

**Few facts about GUI applications in Java:**

**-** In **Java GUI** applications the `main()` method is **short-lived**, **after scheduling the construction of GUI** in the `Event Dispatcher Thread` (EDT) **it quits**.

**-** So its `EDT's` **responsibility to handle the GUI**.

**Now coming to your code:**

**- Initial** Thread is the `main()` thread, and `EDT` is the **GUI Thread**.

**-** In EX1 you are forcing the GUI to run on the `main()` thread which is a wrong way to do it, where as in EX2 when you use the `GridBagLayoutTester` which **extends JPanel**, `main()` thread gets an **early chance to quite by delegating the work of GUI to the EDT**.

**-** `main()` method should be used on to execute the `EventQueue.invokeLater()` method which further deals with the GUI, this will **help the UI to be responsive and avoid dealing with any Non-UI work.**

**-** Moreover Java has `SwingUtilities` Class that does a **great synchronization between** the `UI` and `Non-UI` work on the `UI` and `Non-UI` thread respectively.

**Eg: The proper way of doing it.......**

```
public class Test extends JFrame{

   public Test(){

       this.setSize(300,300);
       this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }


  public static void main(String[] args){


       EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable(){

              public void run(){

                   new Test().setVisible(true);

                }


           });

   }


}
```

Comment: Thanks you for your answer, I know we should use invokeLater when deals with GUI. I just do some example to learn about EDT. I doesn't clear why actionPeform() is invoked from EDT but componentAdded() is not. Could you explain me more about this ?

Comment: @Tuan this is actually quite easy: your main method is run on a "Main-Thread" initiated by the JVM, therefore the main method is not run on the EDT and whatever you do in your main method will never be. However, all Swing events are on the EDT, hence your `ActionEvent` is also on the EDT. The avoid having later problems just use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` at the very beginning of your `main` so that everything else is run properly on the EDT.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet thats right............... and yes i added the SwingUtilities in my answer. I left this on purpose so to keep this simple. So i just kept the answer sticking to main() and EDT thread. But yes...thanks once again..